# Firebase initialization in case of Multiple sender id

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have multiple sender id in project. As per [Firebase Document](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html), below is the code for Firebase initialization:

```
FirebaseOptions.Builder builder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
.setApplicationId("ApplicationId")
.setApiKey("your_api_key")
.setDatabaseUrl("https://your-app.firebaseio.com")
.setStorageBucket("your-app.appspot.com");

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, builder.build());
```

Below is the reference:

[Use multiple projects in your application](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application)

App is receiving push notification from multiple Firebase project/ multiple sender Id. Can I use default initialization (using google-services.json)  or initialization would be done manually as per the mentioned code/link?

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per question.

Comment: Sorry for that, I will take care next time.